# Prove that the systems are orthonormal bases in the space $L_2[0, \pi]$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is as follows: Prove that $\{\sqrt{\frac{2}{π}}\sin({(n-\frac{1}{2}) t})\}_{n =1, ...,\infty}$ and $\{\sqrt{\frac{2}{π}}\cos({(n-\frac{1}{2}) t})\}_{n =1, ...,\infty}$ are orthonormal bases in $L_2[0,π]$.

I have shown that the systems are orthonormal. It remains to show that this is the basis.

I thought to show completeness by the fact that there is no function other than zero and orthogonal to all the functions of this system. But something doesn't add up.

Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong, or thinking for that matter?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Note that $t \to \pi-t$ sends one system in more or less the other, so it is enough to prove the result for the first system.

Comment: I wanted to show the completeness of the system. And if the orthonormal system is complete, then it is the basis. I tried to calculate the scalar product of this function with a common element of the system. If the scalar product is zero, then how to show that the function is zero? But I didn't figure out this part of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a unitary isomorphism $Uf(x)=e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}f(x)$ on the $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$. Applying it to the standard basis of $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$, i.e. to $e^{ikx}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we obtain the system $e^{i(k-\frac{1}{2})x}$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ that will also be a basis of $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$.

Now, consider $f(x)\in L_2[0,\pi]$ and denote $F(x)$ -- odd extension of a function $f$ to a $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$. Let $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^\pi f(x)\sin\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)xdx=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $$0=\int\limits_{0}^\pi f(x)\sin\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)xdx=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)\sin\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)xdx=$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)\sin\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)xdx-\frac{i}{2}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)\cos\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)xdx=-\frac{i}{2}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi F(x)e^{i(k-\frac{1}{2})x}dx.$$
Thus, $F$ belongs to the orthogonal complement to the linear span of $e^{i(k-\frac{1}{2})x}, \;k\in\mathbb{N}$, i.e. $F$ belongs to the closure of the linear span of $e^{i(k-\frac{1}{2})x},\;k=0,-1,-2,...$ If $F(x)=\sum c_ke^{i(k-\frac{1}{2})x}$, then, due to oddness, $\sum c_k\cos\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)x=0$. By multiplying this equality scalarly on $\cos\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)x$ on the $[0,\pi]$, we get that all $c_k=0$, thus $F(x)\equiv0$.

Another way to solve the problem is to choose a suitable Sturm-Liouville problem, the solution of which is the required systems of functions.

Comment: Where are you using $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \cos \left(\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right) dx = 0$ ?

Comment: Nowhere. I considered the problem only for the sine system. For the cosine system, the reasoning is similar.

Comment: So $\{sin((k-\frac{1}{2})x) :k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L_2([0,\pi])$. and $\{cos((k-\frac{1}{2})x) :k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L_2([0,\pi])$. Both are 2 different bases and doesnt work together. Am i right ? Interesting !

Comment: Yes, these are two different bases.